# inspect ssh connection is not working but ssh connection is allow

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, inspec

I am trying to run all my inspec test before to deploy the chef recipe. I want to know what is the initial state of my instances.

I tested the ssh connection with:

```
ssh -i $HOME/key.pem centos@server_ip_address
```

and the connection is allow, but when I tried to run the inspect test again the server:

```
inspec exec ntp/test/integration/ntp.rb -t ssh://centos@server_ip_address -i /home/centos/key.pem
```

I got this error:

```
I, [2017-01-17T14:10:32.835995 #2416]  INFO -- : [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user centos@server_ip_address>)
I, [2017-01-17T14:10:34.619150 #2416]  INFO -- : [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user centos@server_ip_address>)
I, [2017-01-17T14:10:36.403860 #2416]  INFO -- : [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user centos@server_ip_address>)
I, [2017-01-17T14:10:38.188401 #2416]  INFO -- : [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user centos@server_ip_address>)
W, [2017-01-17T14:10:39.971832 #2416]  WARN -- : [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user centos@server_ip_address>)
Transport error, can't connect to 'ssh' backend: SSH session could not be established
```

I do not know where is the error. Any suggestion ?

### Inspec info

```
chef gem list | grep inspec

inspec (1.9.0, 1.7.2)
```

Comment: I assume key as hostname is a typo (`-t ssh://centos@key`) or it isn't? Is there anything in server logs?

Comment: You should have to look the train gem in the inspec. It is the one which is creating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I spent the whole morning and part of the afternoon searching and I found a solution [here](https://github.com/chef/inspec/issues/393#event-530776190)

I execute:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

and then added my key to the agent:

```
ssh-add key.pem
```

So now I am able to run the inspec tests without the keys just executing:

```
inspec exec cookbooks/ntp/test/integration/default/ -t ssh://centos@server_ip_address
```

Ok, this is a partial solution because I am still looking for using the `-i` and use the key as argument. The issue is still there.